# python: compare list containing multiple lists with a single different list

Tags: python

I am solving an issue where I have to make a program to correct evidence. The program receives a feedback and answers "n" students and compares it with the supplied template. The responses of all students are put into a single list. My problem is, how to compare the list of responses to the feedback and print an individual score for each student.

Ex:

```
answer_teacher = ['a','b','d','e','f']
answer_student = [['a','b','f','e','f'],['a','a','d','e','f'], ...]
```

Comment: This is a very basic programming problem, you should be able to solve it by yourself and we can help you doing so if you show us what you have tried.

Comment: At least try. What is the purpose of learning programming if you don't want to program.

Comment: More answer can be found here - https://www.google.co.in/?ion=1&espv=2#q=compare+two+lists+python

Answer (score 2):

without seeing what you tried im going to give you this answer ... just be prepared to explain your solution to the teacher

```
print([sum(a==b for a,b in zip(student,answer_teacher))*1.0/len(answer_teacher) for student in answer_student])
```

Comment: I remember my first class in computer science in high school. My teacher didn't care how we got our answers nor if we fully understood the material. Some will only care if you have something to hand in so they don't look bad.

Comment: "just be prepared to explain your solution to the teacher"  --> +1

Comment: No need for `* 1.0` if you're on Py3 (or did `from __future__ import division` in Py2). And even faster (requires Py3, or importing Py3-like `map` from `future_builtins` or `itertools.imap` in Py2), replace `sum(a==b for a,b in zip(student,answer_teacher))` with `sum(map(operator.eq, student, answer_teacher))` (requires importing `operator` module obviously) to push comparison and summation work entirely to C layer (replacing `zip` + genexpr with just `map`). Note: This is just me noting alternatives and version quirks; the answer as written is 100% fine.